# Is it possible to align text at start in a flutter button

Tags: android, ios, flutter

i have a very simple button:

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () => print(title),
   color: Colors.white,
   elevation: 1,
   child: AutoSizeText(
     title,
     maxLines: 1,
   ),
);
```

but i need to align the text at the start, is this possible. I am aware of the InkWell option, but i was not able to both get a border and the splash effect.

Comment: From my experience when your splash is not showing because it's overlapping with the `RaiseButton`, try using stack making the transparent container which contain the splash effect in the second stack

Answer (score 0):

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () => print(title),
   color: Colors.white,
   elevation: 1,
   child: Text('Button',),
),
```

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, i wasn't looking for a way to center but a way to align the text at start

Answer (score 0):

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () => print(title),
   color: Colors.white,
   elevation: 1,
   child: Text('Your Text Here', textAlign: TextAlign.left)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

> this is worked with me perfectly

```
Positioned(
        bottom: 0.0,
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ButtonTheme(
                minWidth: 100,
                height: 40,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    child: Text(
                      'SKIP',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
              ButtonTheme(
                minWidth: 100,
                height: 40,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    child: Text(
                      'Next',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```